# Where can I view cinematics I've unlocked?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't find where to view cinematics that I have "unlocked" (by having them occur naturally for game progress). Am I just missing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go all the way back to the login screen, there's a Cinematics button. You don't even need to log in.

[image]

If you can't see some cutscenes(possibly due to a corrupted/missing cinematics file), [this thread](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209931810) details a workaround that unlocks all of them:

> Open My Documents\Diablo III\D3Prefs.txt (for win7/vista, not sure where it is in xp or os-x) in notepad and change the "PlayedCutscene" lines to (or add them if they are missing)
>
> PlayedCutscene0 "31"
>
> PlayedCutscene1 "31"
>
> PlayedCutscene2 "23"
>
> PlayedCutscene3 "143"
>
> Also right-click the file and check the properties so it isn't set to read only for some reason.
>
> Note that this unlocks all cinematics so if you don't want to spoil anything don't watch them all :)

Make sure the game is closed before you do this.