# Can I watch Diablo 3 cutscenes again?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I view cinematics I’ve unlocked?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68469/where-can-i-view-cinematics-ive-unlocked)

In Diablo 3, sometimes my computer locks up during the cutscenes, so they aren't so fluid (and other times they play wonderfully ... I know, things I need to fix on my end, but I digress)

How can I watch the cutscenes afterwards? Specifically I'm looking at the mid-act cutscenes, but would love to re-view any that I've already seen. I'm not looking to hack the disk, but prefer to do it through the game console.

I've two laptops, and MBP and a Win7 x64 if this helps.

Comment: also, should someone with +300 rep introduce [tag:cutscene] or [tag:cutscenes] since there are a lot of Q on cutscenes and no tag on them ...

Comment: Also related - [if there are some missing/bugged in that menu](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68720/where-can-i-view-tyraels-sacrifice-cinematic-in-game) and [if you also want to review dialog](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68604/is-there-another-way-to-listen-to-quest-dialogues-or-watch-in-game-cinematics-if).

Comment: Are you referring to the pre-rendered cinematics or the in-game "events" where the characters dialog with each other?  The former can be accessed, the latter cannot.

Comment: Re: tags, we tend to purge tags like that, so it's unlikely that it will be created, and it would probably be removed if it was.

Comment: Why would that tag be removed? Also, your linked Q was what I wanted. Is cutscene not a good synonym for cinematic?