# Where can I view Tyrael's Sacrifice cinematic in-game?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Diablo 3 [main menu has a Cinematics button](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68469/where-can-i-view-cinematics-ive-unlocked):

[image]

Where you can choose to view cinematics you've unlocked:

[image]

Except you'll notice there's no option to view [Tyrael's Sacrifice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzjptdaBYsk) again.

[image]

Where's the option to view Tyrael's Sacrifice again?

Comment: I didn't know it was missing. :( Hopefully theres a fix. That was easily the best cinematic in the game.

Comment: I almost panicked thinking this was a spoiler... And then I realized I'd already seen the cinematic. Phew...

Comment: Eh? [That's weird, it's there for me.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gyeFL.jpg) Speculation: Did you complete all the quests in Act 1, or did you skip past them by joining a multiplayer game in a later act?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209931810
This forum solved this issue for me, i was missing tyrael's sacrifice - the best cutscene!

> Open My Documents\Diablo III\D3Prefs.txt (for win7/vista, not sure
>   where it is in xp or os-x) in notepad and change the "PlayedCutscene"
>   lines to (or add them if they are missing)
>
> PlayedCutscene0 "31"
>   PlayedCutscene1 "31"
>   PlayedCutscene2 "23"
>   PlayedCutscene3 "143"

Answer (score 5):

I just figured it out.

> Cinematics are unlocked **per computer**.

I just started Diablo on my *work* machine and only 3 cinematics are unlocked:

- Act 1: The First Sign
- Act 2: Tyrael's Sacrifice
- Act 2: Caldeum

I guess this is part of Blizzard's ***online only*** and **offline only** system.
If i want access to the cinematics I will have to start over and be sure to not play at work.

Answer (score 5):

#### Log in to your account and load Act 1 Quest 10 to travel to Caldeum.

[image: Return to New Tristam]

#### Your two missing cutscenes (Tyrael's Sacrifice and Caldeum) should play successively in the Act transition. They'll be available in your Cinematics menu from then on.

[image: Cutscenes]

Comment: This would be the answer if the cinematic appeared in the list (i.e. if this answer worked it would certainly be accepted).

Comment: This should work for computers without the unlocked videos

Answer (score 1):

If you played Act 1 in single player could be a bug related to server issues in that moment. Unlocked cinematics can be played also if you are not logged in, but probably the unlock is done through a server-side interaction.

Try to remake Act 1 and see if the cinematic unlocks.