# How to see Diablo vs Imperius

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I view cinematics I've unlocked?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68469/where-can-i-view-cinematics-ive-unlocked)

At the end of act 3, I was asked whether to go to the next act. If I press yes I ended up in heaven without any cut scene.

I think I saw the cut scene once. Don't really know how to trigger it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the game - even before logging in - there's a "cinematics" button on the bottom-left. Click that button to see a list of all the cinematics you have unlocked; click a cinematic to watch it.

If you finished normal and still have some missing cinematics, your "cinematics-unlocked file" may have been corrupted or removed; see [this battle.net discussion thread](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4209931810) on an explanation on how to fix it.